# AndroidManifest.xml writing to file system is there a way

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

is there a setting I can set in AndroidManifest.xml to have my app write to the file system and not just the sdcard?

*cheers

Answer (score 1):

You should use one of the options for data storage defined [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for storing your data. For accessing other places you will probably need root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing a **SQLite database**: here is a [tutorial](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-simple-but-persistent-data-storage/) plus [a overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) and the [sdk reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)